# Gather column name of a table from database

Tags: php, mysql, database

Whats the best way to get the column name of a database table and show them in a php page? I am only able to gather and show the table row.

```
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('...');
$query = "SELECT * FROM ...";

$result = mysql_query($query);

echo "<table class='table'>";
echo '<tr>';
for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($result); $i++) { 
    echo "<th>".mysql_field_name($result, $i)."</th>"; 
}
echo '</tr>';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){  
echo "<tr class='info'><td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>
               <td>" . $row['mail'] . "</td>
               <td>" . $row['number'] . "</td>
               <td>" . $row['price'] . "</td>
               <td>" . $row['paymenttype'] . "</td>
               <td>" . $row['pcname'] . "</td>
               </tr>";  
}
echo "</table>"; 
mysql_close(); 
?>
```

Comment: I see two **major problems** here. 1) You're using an extension that has been removed from PHP for quite some time now. This is especially dangerous since you're saying you're just learning PHP. Please see [the  PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for more details about using the newer APIs. 2) The column name is the key of your `$row` array. So `$row['foo']` is the value of column `foo` in that result row. Your database schema is static and so you should always know what your column names are.

Comment: So i must use Msqli instead as first.

Comment: You can use [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), but whatever you do you **absolutely must NOT** use [the old mysql extension](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php) as it has been deprecated and removed ages ago. PDO is a more elegant interface, in my opinion, but MySQLi can offer you the full vendor-specific set of features native to the MySQL API as PDO is a vendor-agnostic interface. For a beginner just learning PHP I would advice sticking to PDO for now since you probably wont need any of the advanced features MySQLi would have to offer.

Comment: Thank you, I will first change the method i connect to the db and then when it works i wil go through the second part.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-fields.php

```
$result = mysql_query("select * from table"); 

echo '<tr>';
for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($result); $i++) { 
    echo "<th>".mysql_field_name($result, $i)."</th>"; 
}
echo '</tr>';
```

Comment: This works thank you

Answer (score -2):

do a separate query with

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM {table_name}
```

Comment: Updated my question, something like that?

Comment: Pleas explain why this works.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @MeeneshJain how exactly does this not answer the question, the way I read it the OP whats to know how to dynamically read the column names, and this is the way to to it.

Comment: @RohitGupta this query will deliver the column names so you do not have to hard code them

Comment: @tripleb, You are missing the point.  It's not me that you have to explain this to.  You need to edit your post and make it better.  At the moment it is a low quality answer and may get deleted.  Not by me or  Meenesh.  And the down vote is not mine either, yet. We are trying to help you.  Please flesh out your answer.

Comment: I thought it's enough to point to in the correct direction not code the entire program for the OP